# What is Proof of Proof (PoP)?

Tags: blockchain, veriblock

I've been doing some looking at [Veriblock](https://wiki.veriblock.org) regarding Blockchain recently. Does anyone know what "Proof of Proof (PoP)" is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof-of-Proof is a consensus protocol by VeriBlock which allows any blockchain to inherit the full security of Bitcoin in a truly decentralized, trustless, transparent, and permissionless (DTTP) manner.

The white paper describes the mechanics: https://www.veriblock.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/PoP-White-Paper.pdf

It does so by gamifying the publication of data representing a blockchain’s present state to Bitcoin (directly or indirectly) such that any user can participate and receive compensation for enabling blockchains to inherit Bitcoin’s security.